# Converting a String (using Regex) to a usable object

Tags: java, json, regex

For a project we are working with a telnet server where we receive our data from.
After a line is read from a telnet connection i get the following string:

**Original string:**

```
SVR GAME MOVE {PLAYER: "PLAYER", MOVE: "1", DETAILS: ""}
```

I'm trying to convert this to an output I can easily use without too many exploitability occuring.
The desired format would be to easily get(PLAYER) or get. I tried using regex in combination with json see the code below:

```
String line = currentLine;
line = line.replaceAll("(SVR GAME MOVE )", ""); //remove SVR GAME MATCH
line = line.replaceAll("(\"|-|\\s)", "");//remove quotations and - and spaces (=\s)
line = line.replaceAll("(\\w+)", "\"$1\""); //add quotations to every word
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
       JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(line);
       //@todo bug when details is empty causes
       //@todo example string: SVR GAME MOVE {PLAYER: "b", MOVE: "1", DETAILS: ""}
       //@todo string that (line) that causes an error when parsing to json {"PLAYER":"b","MOVE":"1","DETAILS":}
       //@todo Unexpected token RIGHT BRACE(}), i think because "details" has no value
       System.out.println(json.get("PLAYER"));
       System.out.println(json.get("MOVE"));
       System.out.println(json.get("DETAILS"));
       int index = Integer.valueOf(json.get("MOVE").toString());
       for(GameView v : views){
          v.serverMove(index);//dummy data is index 1
       }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is when the details are empty this would result in a Unexpected token RIGHT BRACE(}). Furthermore when players take exploitative name for example quotes in their names the code will crash easily.

**What is the best way to convert the original String to an output where you can get the seperate settings easily(player,move,details)?**

Comment: take the string inside the {} and split at `,` then you can again split at `:`

Comment: You should get the first `{` and the last `}` and consider that your json String. Parse it with your Json parsing library (because REGEX is not appropriate for nested properties)

Comment: I'm not convinced that using a JSON parser is the way to go here.

Comment: @MauricePerry You would recommened using regex?

Comment: @Jouke I believe I would use a regex, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will parse the string and put the variables in a map:

```
    Map<String,String> vars = new HashMap<>();
    String input = "SVR GAME MOVE {PLAYER: \"PLAYER\", MOVE: \"1\", DETAILS: \"\"}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]+): \"([^\"]*)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        vars.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Comment: Just a quick follow up for clarification:   
First group: ([A-Za-z]+):  //Match any characert from A-Z or a-z, + means 1 or more, end with :
So the first group matches every word that ends with :


Second group: "([^"]*)"    //Match the ", then [^"] = match a single characer " that is not in the set,  * = between zero and more times, end with a " .

So the second group matches everything between quotes and checks if it doesn't contain quotes itself?

Comment: Your a regex wizard;) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With [jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) you could do something like:

```
String input = "{PLAYER: \"PLAYER\", MOVE: \"1\", DETAILS: \"\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode yourJson = mapper.readTree(input);
System.out.println(yourJson.get("PLAYER"));
System.out.println(yourJson.get("MOVE"));
System.out.println(yourJson.get("DETAILS"));
```

Comment: would it parse the string? it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Results in com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('P' (code 80)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

The problem is that PLAYER,MOVE&DETAILS do not contain quotes(as in default JSON format).  I tried fixing that with a regex as displayed in my original code. But i can't get it to work properly. Any idea?

Comment: @Jouke yes: the attribute names must be in quotes

Comment: @MauricePerry It will. If you look it with out escapes, it's a valid json.

Comment: @Jouke My input string has escapes just for demo purpose. Without them it becomes valid json.

Comment: @IvanMarkovic the NAMES, as well as the values

Comment: @MauricePerry It indeed is required in the following format "key": "value". The problem is that it's now key: "value"

Comment: I had the same problem in my original code which i posted. It turns out it's quite hard to add the quotes when people are using weird usernames. I tried remove quotations and - and spaces (=\s) then added quotations around every word. The problem is that it's very buggy when people choose weird names or when strings are empty.

Comment: @Jouke that's why IMHO, the use of a JSON parser seems to bring more problems than it solves. I would use a simple ad-hoc parser.

Comment: @MauricePerry My bad. Indeed they need. I thought  you were referring to values.

Comment: I guess @MauricePerry has a point with creating ad-hoc parser. Or if possible, making json valid when produced.